# Android quickblox public chat dialog occupants ids null

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

I have created a public chat using `QBDialog` Type `QBDialogType.PUBLIC_GROUP`, and `Group` is created successfully. Also all the users are able to chat in this `Group`.

But my problem is that when I am getting this group the occupants id `Array` is null. I am using below code to get the group.

```
QBRequestGetBuilder requestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
        requestBuilder.setPagesLimit(100);
        QBChatService.getChatDialogs(QBDialogType.PUBLIC_GROUP, requestBuilder,
                new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBDialog>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBDialog> dialogs,
                            Bundle args) {
                        List<Integer> usersIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        for (QBDialog dialog : dialogs) {
                            System.out.println("Occupants : "+dialog.getOccupants());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(List<String> errors) {
                        System.out.println("Error : "+errors);
                    }
                });
```

Is there any way to get all occupants id of a `Public Group`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Public Group doesn't have the occupants ids because it's an open group, so any user can join it, don't need to store occupants ids

Comment: QBRequestGetBuilder requestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
requestBuilder.addParameter("name", nameOfPublicChatRoom);  add Parameter method not found with sdk 2.2.1 is there any alternate method.

Comment: Hi, I'm currently working on a proof of concept using quickblox.

Would you know if this is documented? I had been wondering why it was not updating the occupantsIDs property myself.

I'm using JS SDK but experienced the same thing.

Comment: Thank you. How to join a public group by group_id.